# Change Desktop background using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to change desktop background using VB.NET?

I'd like to change the icons too?

I plan on making a VB.NET program that can automatically make Windows XP look like Mac in just one click.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Steps you will do.
Start visual studio 2005 and create a new window project.
Set the following properties of the form

```
'Text = "Set Wallpaper"
'Size = “1024,750”
```

Now drip a picture box control on the form and set its following properties.

```
'Size = “1024,725”
'Sizemode = ”centerimage”
```

Drop a two button controls on the form and set its following properties as below.

```
'First button control.
 
'Name = " btgetimage"
'Text = " Brows For Image"
 
'Second button control.
 
'Name = " btsetwallpaper"
'Text = " Set Wallpaper"
```

Now drop an openfiledialog control on the form.
Open you code window and import the following namespace.

```
Imports System.IO.Directory
```

Now declare the function and variables as below which will use win API's to set the wallpaper.

```
Private Const SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER As Integer = &H14

Private Const SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE As Integer = &H1

Private Const SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE As Integer = &H2

Private Declare Auto Function SystemParametersInfo Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal uAction As Integer, ByVal uParam As Integer, ByVal lpvParam As String, ByVal fuWinIni As Integer) As Integer

Const WallpaperFile As String = "c:\wallpaper.bmp"
```

Make a function as below.

```
   Friend Sub SetWallpaper(ByVal img As Image)
    
    Dim imageLocation As String
    
    imageLocation = My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyPictures, WallpaperFile)
    
    Try
    
    img.Save(imageLocation, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
    
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, imageLocation, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE Or SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE)
    
    Catch Ex As Exception
    
    MsgBox("There was an error setting the wallpaper: " & Ex.Message)
    
    End Try
    
    End Sub
```

Now in the click event of the first button write the following code to open and get the image.

```
OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\"

OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "JPG|*.jpg|Bitmap|*.bmp"

Dim dialogresult As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog

If dialogresult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

PictureBox1.ImageLocation = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

btsetwallpaper.Enabled = True

End If
```

In the click event of the second button write following code to set the wallpaper.

```
SetWallpaper(Me.PictureBox1.Image)

MessageBox.Show("Wallpaper has been changed", "Set Wallpaper", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```

Comment: did you fing this at http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/421.html [Changing the Desktop Wallpaper Programmatically] ?

Comment: @astander - would it make a difference if he did??

Comment: How about for dual screens? I'm about to build something since Windows 7 doesn't let you set 2 different backgrounds for dual monitors.

Comment: So glad this whole solution was in an answer and not relying on an external link - the external link is no longer valid!

Answer (score 1):

Try this program :

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Desktop

    Public Shared SPI_SETDESKTOPWALLPAPER As Integer = 20
    Public Shared SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE As Integer = 1
    Public Shared SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE As Integer = 2

    Public Shared Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)
        If (args.Length = 1) Then
            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKTOPWALLPAPER, 0, args(0), _ 
            (SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE Or SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE))
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Declare Sub SystemParametersInfo Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal action As Integer, _ 
        ByVal iparam As Integer, ByVal vparam As String, ByVal option As Integer)

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Win32` '`user32`' for change the desktop background.
you need to declare user32 pi function `SystemParametersInfo` like as:

```
Private Declare Function SystemParametersInfo Lib “user32″ 
Alias “SystemParametersInfoA” (ByVal uAction As Integer, ByVal uParam As Integer, 
ByVal lpvParam As String, ByVal fuWinIni As Integer) As  Integer
```

and call this function with valid parameters

you can also check this link, this is the good article for learning how to change desktop background in vb.net

http://www.authorcode.com/how-to-set-desktop-background-in-vb-net/

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple and functional code that sets your desktop using only a timer

```
Public Class Form1

   Dim Location As String

   Private Declare Function SystemParametersInfo Lib "user32" Alias "SystemParametersInfoA" (ByVal uAction As Integer, ByVal uParam    As Integer, ByVal lpvParam As String, ByVal fuWinIni As Integer) As    Integer

   Private Const SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
   Private Const UPDATEINIFILE = &H1

   Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

       Location = ("image directory.jpg")

       PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Danny\Desktop\Hacker.jpg")

       PictureBox1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch

       SystemParametersInfo(SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, Location, UPDATEINIFILE)

   End Sub     End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

My personal version timered with 1 button, 1 checkbox, 1 timer (10 seconds) and 1 openfiledialog:

```VBNet
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
    Private Declare Function SystemParametersInfo Lib “user32” Alias “SystemParametersInfoA” (ByVal uAction As Integer, ByVal uParam As Integer, ByVal lpvParam As String, ByVal fuWinIni As Integer) As Integer

    'Declare two constant
    Private Const SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
    Private Const UPDATEINIFILE = &H1
    Private Const SENDWININICHANGE As Integer = 2
    Dim numfiles As Integer = 0
    Dim numtimer As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "JPEG Files|*.jpg|BMP Files|*.bmp|PNG Files|*.png|GIF Files|*.gif"
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            If CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
                SystemParametersInfo(SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString, UPDATEINIFILE Or SENDWININICHANGE)
            Else
                Dim file As String
                For Each file In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
                    numfiles += 1
                Next file
                Timer1.Start()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            numfiles = 0
            numtimer = 0
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If numtimer < numfiles Then
            SystemParametersInfo(SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, OpenFileDialog1.FileNames(numtimer).ToString, UPDATEINIFILE Or SENDWININICHANGE)
            numtimer += 1
        Else
            numtimer = 1
            SystemParametersInfo(SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, OpenFileDialog1.FileNames(numtimer).ToString, UPDATEINIFILE Or SENDWININICHANGE)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```